# Jetson Nano Picocluster not accessible from network

Tags: networking, ip, dhcp, cluster, gateway

I recently received a Picocluster with five Jetson Nano boards running MicroK8S. The cluster has a built in switch, which I know works as I can route my own network traffic through it just fine. All five boards are also connected to that switch. Currently I am trying to access the cluster from my laptop, but just can't figure out how to do this. My net is 192.168.1.0/24, and all the boards in the cluster are on subnet 10.1.10.0/24. Every board has the following configuration (with ascending IP addresses) in `/etc/network/interface`

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 10.1.10.240
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 10.1.10.1
dns-nameservers 10.1.10.1 8.8.8.8
```

When trying to ping google from any board in the cluster I get a timeout, so they seem to not actually be connected to the internet. The way I want this cluster to work is by having the master node act as a sort of gateway to the cluster, being able to route network traffic to my router, and allowing my laptop to access the cluster subnet. I also currently can not see any of the boards using nmap, arp or any other tool. How would I go about fixing this? Please tell me if outputs from any other files would help :)